# How to extend a CollectionType with a Protocol and a where clause?

Tags: swift, swift2

I have this protocol definition:

```
protocol BarChartDataConvertible {
    var barChartData: BarChartData { get }
}
```

And I would like to extend a CollectionType where the elements are of a specific type, with that protocol:

```
extension CollectionType where Generator.Element == DataPoint {

    // This works, by I also want it to be enforced by the BarChartDataConvertible
    // var barChartData: BarChartData { ... }

}
```

How can I do this?

```
[DataPoint(), DataPoint()].barChartData
```

Comment: If your question is *"Can I make a collection conform to protocol P if its elements conform to P"* then the answer is: At present, you can't.

Comment: Close, but no. The question is: can I extend a collection, where the elements are of Type DataPoint, conform to a protocol. I edited the question for better clarification.

Comment: You cannot declare "conditional conformance to a protocol". But with `var barChartData: BarChartData { return someThingUsefulHere }` in the extension, your above code should compile.

Comment: You are right, there is a swift-evolution proposal regarding this issue: https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20151207/001762.html if you want to provide the answer I'll marke it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define extension methods which apply only to a restricted
type of the generic placeholders

```
extension CollectionType where Generator.Element == DataPoint {
    var barChartData: BarChartData { return somethingUseful }
}
```

and then

```
[DataPoint(), DataPoint()].barChartData
```

compiles. But you cannot declare a "conditional conformance to
a protocol", such as

```
extension CollectionType: DataPoint where Generator.Element == DataPoint { ... }
```

Such a feature is discussed on the Swift Evolution mailing list,
starting at [[swift-evolution] [Manifesto] Completing Generics](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160229/011666.html):

> *Conditional conformances
>
> Conditional conformances express the notion that a generic type will
> conform to a particular protocol only under certain circumstances. For
> example, Array is Equatable only when its elements are Equatable:
>
> extension Array : Equatable where Element : Equatable { }

but it is not available in Swift 2 and – as far as I can see –
not on the current lists of proposals for Swift 3 at https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution.